# jQuery Asual Address fails

Tags: jquery, html

It's me again with another problem of deep linking. I'm using Asual Address and everything seems to work fine. Except one thing:

If a link is pressed for the second time in a row, nothing happens. For me it is quite hard to explain. For better understanding, I added a jsfiddle, so you can see for yourselves.

http://jsfiddle.net/CKUPx/6/show/

http://jsfiddle.net/CKUPx/6/

As the documentation of ausal address is really confusing to me, I might have failed at something simple. If anybody has any suggestions how to solve this, please let me know.

My guess is, that is fails at my attempt to use the history.pushState, but I can't figure out what it is.

This is my jquery:

```
var $ov = $('#overlay'),
    $ld = $('#load');


$ov.click(function (e) {

    history.pushState(null, "Title", "/");
    $ld.empty();
    $ld.hide();
    $ov.hide();

});

$.address.init(function () {

    $('.item a').address(function () {
        return $(this).attr('href').substring(20);

    });

}).change(function (event) {

    if ($ld.is(':empty')) {
        $ld.hide();
        $ov.hide();
    }

    $ld.load(event.value + ' #contain', function () {

        if ($ld.not(':empty')) {
            $ld.show();
            $ov.show();
        }
        if ($ld.is(':empty')) {
            $ld.hide();
            $ov.hide();
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the `$.address.value()` when applying the url:

```
$('.item a').address(function () {
        return $.address.value($(this).attr('href').substring(20));
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/xE9Jg/)

Comment: Don't think that's the behavior he's looking for. The overlay doesn't work anymore in your example.

Comment: @TimVermaelen did not test all browsers but it works in chrome

Comment: i changed that part in the fiddle and it works. I will test it as soon as possible. Thank you!

Comment: hmm, it's strange, could be a jsfiddle quirck as I have it now in my forked fiddle, but not in the OP's edited one ... beats me, so my comment is invalid.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cSm2u/show/ check this forked fiddle and click a link. It returns [object Object] instead of the links href.

Comment: For whatever reason, you have run my forked fiddle referenced in the answer before it works, as stated could be a jsfiddle quirk

Comment: It works when you edit a fiddle and press run, but not when you load fresh. In any case, I believe this answer is correct.

Comment: I created one from scratch and it seems to work better without having to do the run updating link in answer

Comment: Can you link that fiddle? I'd like to take a look at it :)

Comment: @INC if this solved your problem plz mark at the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code, and everything seems to be working fine.

Not so sure about it, but I think it might be something is this way.

When you hit the second time the same link, it actually **don't** change the URL, so the plugin ignores that action just because you've already load that content.

Comment: yeah my good sir, thats exactly what I need to fix. Any suggestions on that matter? No lie, I'm clueless. 
  
I think address can't trigger twice, because the content a link refers to, already did get loaded and the URL changed. No change -> address doesn't fire.

I thought I could just change the URL with pushState and it would work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't actually CHANGE anything when you click twice and since I'm not really familiar with the idea/library behind it ... here goes my "dirty" solution:

```
// add a timestamp to your value so it's always different
$('.item a').address(function (ev) {
    return $(this).attr('href').substring(20) + '_' + new Date().getTime();
});

// split the event value by the underscore
$ld.load(event.value.split('_')[0] + ' #contain', function () {});
```

It works, but it's not an ideal solution.